# forcing a tar source to be downloaded locally rather remote one from bbappend file

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe

I have a .bb file which has the following snippet

```
SRC_URI = "ftp://..... \
        "
```

I cannot change this recipe file. So i want to create a .bbappend file for this recipe and want bitbake to fetch the source (tar) from my filesytem instead from the internet (via ftp).

The fetch from my local drive works if i delete "ftp.." entry in the recipe file. But unfortunately i cannot change the recipe file.

Has any one got any idea how i can achieve this.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: can any one help me. i basically want to remove a source file from "SRC_URI" in a recipe from a corresponding bbappend file. The opposite of SRC_URI_append.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [`remove` bitbake override](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#removing-override-style-syntax), like this:

```
SRC_URI_remove = "ftp://....."
```

But it's strange that you need to change `SRC_URI` in that way. If you're not changing the file contents, you should be [using mirrors](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#source-mirrors) for your source files, and if you're changing things, it's more appropriate to append a patch to your `SRC_URI`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to SRC_URI_remove.

I am not changing the file contents. The recipe belongs to third party delivery which i cannot change. But fetch of SRC_URI="ftp:.." in the recipe some how doesnt work in our build system due to probable proxy issues. fetching the same link outside of build system works. So i want to download the tar ball, and remove the "ftp:" link in the SRC_URI and add a local path in it. Do you think its a good work around the problem.

Mirrors: I think premirrors is also a good option for me.

Comment: @srik: For this case mirrors are exactly what you need, it's good to have some internal mirror anyway and it will solve the problem of missing file in its original SRC_URI path.